# Kernel dead running a simple average operation using Python

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am running a simple average operation over three columns. I am transforming the monthly data into a quarterly average. The data looks like this:

```
2000.1 2000.2 2000.3....
18     15     27
```

I want to transform it into

```
2000.q1 
20
```

Here is what I have so far:

def convert_housing_data_to_quarters():
    '''Converts the housing data to quarters and returns it as mean 
    values in a dataframe. This dataframe should be a dataframe with
    columns for 2000q1 through 2016q3, and should have a multi-index
    in the shape of ["State","RegionName"].

```
Note: Quarters are defined in the assignment description, they are
not arbitrary three month periods.
The resulting dataframe should have 67 columns, and 10,730 rows.
'''
# read in the zillow housing data 
zillow_df = pd.read_csv('City_Zhvi_AllHomes.csv')
print(zillow_df.iloc[1,1])
print(len(zillow_df))
# slice from 2000q1 to 2016q3
print(zillow_df.columns)
print(zillow_df.columns[6:51])
zillow_df.drop(zillow_df.columns[6:51],axis=1,inplace=True)
# generate quarterly average 
y = 2000
q = 1
for i in range(67):
    y_q = str(y)+'q'+str(q)
    #print(y_q)
    print(zillow_df.columns[6+(i)*3])
    print(zillow_df[zillow_df.columns[6+(i)*3]])
    zillow_df[y_q]=(zillow_df[zillow_df.columns[6+(i)*3]]+zillow_df[zillow_df.columns[6+1+(i)*3]]+zillow_df[zillow_df.columns[6+2+(i)*3]])/3
    q=q+1
    if q==5:
        q=1
        y=y+1  
return zillow_df.head()
```

I think that my code is correct but every time I run it in ipython notebook. It says kernel dead. I am not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need convert columns names [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_datetime.html) and then to `month period` by [`to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.to_period.html) first.

Then [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) by `quarters` and aggregate `mean` (`axis=1` is for aggregate by columns names).

Last convert columns by [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html) to strings by format:

```
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns, format='%Y.%m').to_period('m')
print (df)
   2000-01  2000-02  2000-03
0       18       15       27

df = df.resample('Q', axis=1).mean()
df.columns = df.columns.strftime('%Y.q%q')
print (df)
   2000.q1
0       20
```

Comment: Could you explain why this change is necessary and what caused the kernel to die.

Comment: Hard question, but simpliest answer is using loops in pandas is not optimalized and really slow. So maybe run out memory? Maybe some problematic data? Maybe larger data? But the best is used some vectorized solutions like `resample`, I think it works here perfectly.